# Traduction de « need » : Nécessité ou besoin, quelle est la différence ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, synonymes

> Need to predict the overall behavior of automotive components.

Je me demande quelle est la différence entre la traduction :

> Besoin de prédire le comportement global des composants automobiles.

et celle-ci :

> Nécessité de prédire le comportement global des composants automobiles.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« Besoin » implique un état de chose qui s'impose sur le plan des aspirations plutôt que sur le plan d'un absolu logique comme le fait « nécessité »; le **besoin** d'un bout de papier et d'un crayon pour faire une opération arithmétique est ce dont il est question lorsqu'on pense à faire une opération;

> Le **besoin** d'un crayon pour cette lettre m'a fait courir au magasin ce matin.

« Un crayon  m'est nécessaire pour cette lettre.» ne se dira qu'exceptionnellement.

Considéré sur le plan d'un contexte  procédural on dit plutôt « nécessité »;

> Pour faire une opération arithmétique la **nécessité** d'un bout de papier et d'un crayon ou celle d'un calculateur est absolue.

Comment: Une nécessité est un besoin impérieux, un *requirement*.